# Как объединить две формы в программе?

Tags: c#, winforms

`Form1` это сама программа, а `Form2` это тоже самое что и `Form1` только сама форма меньше и не имеет всех кнопок с `Form1`. Это что-то вроде музыкального плеера, `Form1` это сам плеер, а `Form2` это мини плеер. Можно сделать так чтобы функции с `Form1` работали на `Form2`? То есть чтобы не создавать тех же функций на `Form2`.

Comment: унаследуйте обе формы от одного базового класса

Comment: реализуйте плеер в отдельном классе (не форме), передайте на него ссылку в обе формы и дергайте за методы. Стандартное разделение логики и вида, сможете потом еще легко портировать на WPF, другую графическую платформу или даже в консоль

Comment: Можете ответить поподробнее куда нажимать и что делать? Не знаю как сделать.